# Nextgen gallery 2.1.46 remove title in image browser using CSS code

Tags: wordpress, image, title, nextgen-gallery, next-generation-plugin

I am trying to remove the title from an image browser gallery using the Nextgen gallery plugin (v. 2.1.46) and Wordpress (4.4.4).

I have been instructed to go to Gallery > Other Options > Styles and modify the CSS code. But, I am not having luck with the code to remove these titles. So far I have tried:

title=""

title="display:none;"

Could someone please help me and let me know if I am putting in the correct code? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Add this custom css:

```
.ngg-imagebrowser > h3 {
  display: none !important;
}
```